# pgadmin3 connect to server failed

Tags: linux, postgresql, pgadmin

I just installed pgadmin3, when iam trying to connect to a server it throws error like this,.

```
(pgadmin3:8963): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from `GtkFileChooserButton' to `GtkBin'

(pgadmin3:8963): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_modify_style: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

How to resolve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Those are harmless messages, despite how they sound, and are not related to the problem you are having. What is the error when you try to connect to the server?

Comment: Getting error like this
    "Connecting to database failed,."

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: There should be more error message than that. Can you show the *full* error message text, with the entire message? At a guess, the server: isn't running, isn't listening on the address you're trying to connect to, is firewalled off, is unreachable on the network, doesn't allow connections from your host in pg_hba.conf, requires SSL which you're not using, .... endless possibilities